# If screen resolution then show div

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

I need help showing a `div` if the screen resolution is larger then `700px`.

The div:

```
div style="width:70%;margin-left:225px;"
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with PHP and javascript, just tag css, or better just google about media queries

Comment: do with  [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  yourDivSelector{      // div id or class or any other selector
      display:block
    }
}
```